# Compiler keeps saying undefined constructor for Scanner

Tags: java, compiler-errors

The constructor java.util.Scanner(java.util.Scanner) is undefined
I don't understand why it keeps saying its undefined
and the NoSuchElementException says it cant be resolved to a type and the in.Close will not work either

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MatchUp
{
public static void main(String args[]){

printHeader();
readFile(args[0]);


}
 //********************************************************************    
public static void readFile(String filename)       //Method to read file 
 {

 try
 {
File in = new File(filename);
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inFile);
int count = 0;

while(inFile.hasNextLine()){
String line = inFile.nextLine();
String out = "";

for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i ++){
char ch = line.charAt(i);
out = out + ch;

if(ch == '{'){
count = count + 1;
out= out + " " + count;
}
  else if (ch == '}'){
  out= out + " " + count;
  if(count > 0){
    count = count -1;
  }
   }
   }
   }
   }

  catch (FileNotFoundException exception){ 
     System.out.println("File not found."); }
  catch (NoSuchElementException exception) { 
     System.out.println("File contents invalid."); }
  catch (IOException exception) { 
     exception.printStackTrace(); 
  } 
  finally
  {
  in.close();
  }
  }
```

Comment: Can you post the shortest complete snippet of code that generates the error? See http://sscce.org/

Comment: spend more time on formatting your code in a neat and tidy fashion and you will spend less time trying to read it, this is a mess

Comment: well I'm new at this so it's not perfect

Comment: Scanner is saying nothing. The *compiler* is saying something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(inFile);
        ^^^^^^               ^^^^^^
```

makes no sense. You are probably looking for

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(in);
        ^^^^^^               ^^
```